# In Jersey 2.X, a Feature is instantiated by HK2. How can I use Factories I've also added?

Tags: jersey-2.0, hk2

In the strange, strange dependency injection world of Jersey, you can include an `AbstractBinder` (but maybe not just a `Binder`) as one of the objects in the return value of your `Application`'s `getSingletons()` method.

That `AbstractBinder` can then call various `bind()` methods from within its `configure()` method, which Jersey, but no other JAX-RS implementation, is guaranteed to call—and hence you can link implementations to interfaces, which lets you do a semblance of dependency injection from that point forward in your application.  That is, once you've done that, then injection points within, say, your resource classes will be "filled" by the implementations you've bound.

(You can also do this with factory classes, so that you bind a particular factory method's return value to a contract it implements.)

OK, fine.

Jersey also lets you place a `Class` that implements `Feature` into the return value of your `Application`'s `getClasses()` method.  Fine.  This `Feature` class will be instantiated by HK2 under the covers—make a mental note of that!—and its `configure(FeatureContext)` method will be called at some point.  At that point, the `Feature` may register some additional stuff by calling `FeatureContext#register()` and handing it whatever it wants to register. 
 (Presumably this is all a fairly complicated façade on top of HK2's `DynamicConfiguration` machinery.)

Anyway, since a `Feature` is instantiated by HK2 (remember?), it follows that you can `@Inject` things into its constructor, or have injection points elsewhere in the class.  That's cool!  Then HK2 can draw upon all the services it knows of to fill those injection points.  Very neat.

Ah, but the question is: *what is the state of the HK2 world at this point?*  What services can be injected into a `Feature` implementation instantiated as part of A JAX-RS `Application`'s startup sequence?

**If your `Application`'s `getSingletons()` method returns an `AbstractBinder` implementation that binds a `FooImpl` to `Foo` in `Singleton` scope in its `configure()` method, can your `Feature`—"registered" by including its class in the return value of your `Application`'s `getClasses()` method—then inject a `Foo`?**

Comment: The last few sentences are very confusing. Maybe some code showing what is working and what isn't working, and what you expect to work would help.

Comment: You're quite right. I'll remove them.  The bolded part is my main question.  To recap: it appears that items bound in an `AbstractBinder` are not available for injection into a `Feature`.  Is there something that spells out what this behavior should be? Are `Feature`s instantiated before `AbstractBinder` implementations' `configure()` methods are called?

Comment: I imagine it _should_ work. I'll test it and see.

Comment: A straightforward implementation does not work: if you bind something, then register a feature class whose constructor has an injection point, you can't use the stuff you just bound to fill the injection point of the `Feature`.  However, it seems as though you can work around this by having the `Feature`'s injection point take a `Provider`.  However when you do _this_, then if you _also_ try to use one of the bound items in, say, a resource class (to fill one of _its_ injection points), that will not work.

Comment: My suspicion is that the order of setup is not well-defined: when a `Feature`'s constructor is invoked by HK2, there does not seem to be a guarantee that stuff bound via an `AbstractBinder` has been actually bound yet.

Comment: To really blow your mind, try "putting off" the injection resolution via a provider in the `Feature` injection point.  It will work fine now: if you don't call `Provider.get()` until somewhere in the `configure(FeatureContext)` method, everything's fine—presumably the binder does its thing before `Feature#configure(FeatureContext)` is called.  Problem solved, right?  Ah, but now try injecting something that was bound but this time in a resource class.  `MultiException`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152118/discussion-between-peeskillet-and-laird-nelson).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is important to have your `Foo` interface binding proxied, i.e:

```
new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(Foo.class)
                    .proxy(true)
                    .to(FooImpl.class)
                    .in(Singleton.class);
            }
}
```

then dependency injection will be insensitive to the instatination order.